# I cannot tilt my foot inwards

Tags: squats, foot

Just for the record I am not asking for any exercises/physical therapy advices, although if its allowed here, I would be very much thankful for these. I mainly want to know how I can describe the situation with a medical term. Like a word for it.

For the record: I had an ankle sprain on my RIGHT foot a while ago. The thing is that I can tild my foot inwards when standing, no problem. Its nearly the same as on the other foot. But when going into a knees over toes squat, I cant bend it inwards. Now, I have had an overpronation my whole life on both feet. When squatting I can as a result go with my knees way more over my toes than without it. Coming to my point: Due to my ankle sprain, I dont have overpronation on my right foot IN THE *squat position* anymore. Thats makes squatting a weird experience as I have to do something with my left foot to perform a nice squat. I feel like the outside of my foot near the fibula (where its reaching out) is hindering this inwards movement.

Whats the medical term for this not-being-able-to-tild-the-foot-inward thing? so I may find something on google about it.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your description, but I believe that you are referring to supination (outward roll of the foot during normal motion) and pronation (inward rolling of the foot during normal motion).